# How can I use a conditional operator in printf but without the "else" part?

Tags: c, if-statement, printf, conditional-statements

```
printf ("%d ", digitscont(&myarray[i-1]) ? myarray[i-1] : );     // I'd like to do print nothing in the else part.
```

If I leave `:` without anything, it gives me an error:

```
error: expected expression
                printf ("%d ", digitscont(&myarray[i-1]) ? myarray[i-1] : );
                                                                         ^
1 error generated.
```

How can I make my program to print nothing if the function `digitscount` returns 0?

Comment: Why not just do it like this: `if(digitscont(&myarray[i-1] != 0) printf("%d ", myarray[i-1]);`

Comment: I just wanted to know if it was possible to do it inside a printf.

Comment: The way you have it structured, `printf` will always be called; it needs an `int` to print.  You're not providing one in the `else` case.  You can print a value you know means missings, such as `-1`.

Comment: An if() here is the way to go, especially because there is no else, which makes it redundancy-free. You *can*, however, treat printf as an expression (it returns an int, after all) and say `digitscont(&myarray[i-1]) ? printf(...) : 0;`. (The value after the colon is, of course, arbitrary.) If that's readable or good style is debatable; it's surely not idiomatic C and may elicit a compiler warning about an unused value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the way you structured your code, there is no other way for this to happen.

If you look at what your code consists of, you see:

- at the outside, you have `printf("%d ", <something>)`
- inside this, you have a "something" which is your ternary expression.

The `printf` expects this expression to evaluate to a value compatible with `%d`. There is no value which would cause `%d` to output nothing.

The only thin I really could imagine would be

```
printf(digitscont(&myarray[i-1]) != 0 ? "%d " : " ", myarray[i-1]);
```

This will set the format string to `"%d "` if there is an output and to `" "` if there isn't. In the latter case, the numeric argument to `printf()` is ignored.

But that would be bad style. Think about the readers of your code - they are happy if your code can be understood easily.

Answer (score 0):

The ? : is the conditional operator and the expression to the left of the : is the else clause. It would be like writing

```
if (digitscont(&myarray[i-1])) {
    printf ("%d ", myarray[i-1] );
} else {
}
```

so you need to provide an expression after the : that would be evaluated if the logical expresion

```
digitscont(&myarray[i-1])
```

is false

Comment: Yes, I know. I just wanted to know if it was possible to do it inside a printf.

Comment: Only if you are OK with *something* printing even if the expression is false.

Comment: If you need to do it inside of the `printf`, you can move the conditional to the first argument. `printf(digitscont(&myarray[i-1]) ?"%d ":"", myarray[i-1]);` However, I would recommend against this.